# How to properly call initMap to access map object successfully?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my page, I have at least 3 **Ajax** calls and all of them call separate functions that create some **new markers** on same Google map.

On the top of script, I have defined `initMap` function that creates a basic map in global `map` variable.

But now, sometimes everything works, but sometimes it shows following error when a function is called from at least one of ajax methods.

**InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama**

I believe this may be because of Async nature of jQuery Ajax method.

To fix this, I tried checking if **map** is defined or not, whenever response came in Ajax methods. All of them never show like map is undefined. But still there's issue.

So I can't even check if map doesn't exists, call **initMap()** again. Further, I can't call map again and again because it will replace all markers for other functions.

Here's basic code structure that will help you understand:

```
var map;

function initMap(){
}
initMap();

$.ajax({
 //FUNCTION 1 IS CALLED HERE
});


$.ajax({
 //FUNCTION 2 IS CALLED HERE
});


$.ajax({
 //FUNCTION 3 IS CALLED HERE
});

function Func1(){
}

function Func2(){
}

function Func3(){
}
```

**One more important thing:** This issue is observed more in Chrome browser.

Is there any way to do this successfully?

EDIT:

I got the real issue. Everything is fine in my code. The problem is that Google map is loaded twice, 1 is by default (by [PrestaShop](https://www.prestashop.com/en)) and one I'm adding. Now I could use the default loaded map but it shows error that Google map API Key is missing. So how can I append that key without loading map twice?

Answer (score 0):

if your code is below,

```
var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
});
```

try this.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : position,
    setMap : map
});
```

Comment: I got the real issue. Everything is fine in my code. The problem is that Google map is loaded twice, 1 is by default (by PrestaShop) and one I'm adding. Now I could use the default loaded map but it shows error that Google map API Key is missing. So how can I append that key without loading map twice?

Comment: Why is Google map loaded twice? If your googlemap load script is below, first source code "initMap();" is Unnecessary.

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"`